# Best way to include pdfs in an app

Tags: android

I have to develop an app which is basically a pdf reader: it is composed by a list, each list element is a pdf file name, when user clicks on a list element the pdf is popped out, read by a pdf reader installed on the device.

Now, problem is that i'd like to include these pdfs in my app. 
Till now the only way I found is to set them as resource, but the problem is that each time I want to display one of them I'll have to copy it in a public folder and this obviously takes time...isn't there another way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a `ContentProvider` to your app that streams the PDFs to the other process from the resource. For example, [my `StreamProvider`](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-provider) extends Android's `FileProvider` to add support for serving files from raw resources or assets. The demo project, in particular, demonstrates serving a PDF from assets.